# No mouseDragged over JPanel

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I have found a strange problem while trying to write a drag& drop exercise.
It seems, no MouseAdapter.mouseDragged is called while i try to drag a JPanel ( with left click and trying to drag).
The code of interest is following:
public class DragMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter{

```
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
    System.out.println("Mouse dragged on source: " + e.getSource());
 }
}
...
```

Then, somwthere in JFrame:

```
    DragMouseAdapter my = new DragMouseAdapter();

    jPanel1.addMouseListener(my);
    jPanel2.addMouseListener(my);
```

And i see no printout. What is the problem here?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses. You might find [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) of some help also

Answer (score 3):

`mouseDragged` is a part of MouseMotionListener, so you need to use `addMouseMotionListener` instead of (or in addition to) `addMouseListener`.

Edit: Including the following info in my answer instead of in a comment:

A MouseListener handles f.ex. mouse clicks, while a MouseMotionListener handles mouse motions (dragging). There's also a MouseWheelListener. To register each kind of Listener with a component (in your case, a JPanel), the corresponding methods must be called; addMouseListener, addMouseMotionListener, or addMouseWheelListener. For more info, have a look at [How to Write a Mouse-Motion Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) and [MouseAdapter API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html)

Comment: can you tell please what is the difference in addMouseListener/ addMouseMotionListener setting?

Comment: Updated the text of my answer with the info.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `MouseMotionAdapter` instead of `MouseAdapter`. Just change your code to:

```
public class DragMouseAdapter extends MouseMotionAdapter{
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        System.out.println("Mouse dragged on source: " + e.getSource());
    }
}
```

Comment: MouseAdapter has (empty) methods to handle *all* kinds of mouse events, including the motion events such as dragging. It is up to the programmer writing the extending class which methods they want to implement. :)

Comment: i guess the main thing is add an adapter as "addMouseMotionListener", because added as "addMouseListener" handles only clicks. Well, it is not difficult to test